# Visual Studio Creating Bar of Pie

Tags: reporting-services, charts

Is there a way to create a "Bar of Pie" pie chart in Visual Studios like excel? I'm trying to re-create this pie chart in Visual Studios but I'm not sure how to get the "Other, 18" category to expand to a bar chart.

[image]

```
/*Total by Behavior (Pivot Tab)*/
SELECT 
CASE WHEN t.EventGroup = 'Less Than 4 Events' THEN SUM(t.Total) ELSE t.Total END AS TotalCount
, EventGroup
, EventLocation
FROM 
(
SELECT
 COUNT(IncidentNumber) AS Total
, CASE WHEN COUNT(IncidentNumber) <=4 THEN 'Less Than 5 Events' ELSE 
    CASE WHEN [Event Location] = 'HLMED' AND COUNT(IncidentNumber) >= 4 THEN 'MED'
            WHEN [Event Location] = 'HLRAD' AND COUNT(IncidentNumber) >= 4 THEN 'Imaging'
            WHEN [Event Location] IN ('HLOR','HLPACU') AND COUNT(IncidentNumber) >= 4 THEN 'OR/RR'
            WHEN [Event Location] IN ('HLNR','HLOB','HLLD') AND COUNT(IncidentNumber) >= 4 THEN 'OB/LD/NR'
            WHEN [Event Location] = 'HLCV' AND COUNT(IncidentNumber) >= 4 THEN 'PCU'
            WHEN [Event Location] IN ('HLICU','HLPACUOV') AND COUNT(IncidentNumber) >= 4 THEN 'ICU'
            WHEN [Event Location] = 'HLLAB' AND COUNT(IncidentNumber) >= 4 THEN 'LAB'
            WHEN [Event Location] = 'HLSUR' AND COUNT(IncidentNumber) >= 4 THEN 'Surg-Ped'
            WHEN [Event Location] = 'HLRT' AND COUNT(IncidentNumber) >= 4 THEN 'RT'
            WHEN [Event Location] = 'HLFANS' AND COUNT(IncidentNumber) >= 4 THEN 'FANS'
            WHEN [Event Location] = 'HLBUSOFF' AND COUNT(IncidentNumber) >= 4 THEN 'BIZ OFFICE'
            WHEN [Event Location] = 'HLPHA' AND COUNT(IncidentNumber) >= 4 THEN 'PHARM'
            WHEN [Event Location] = 'HLPSYCH' AND COUNT(IncidentNumber) >= 4 THEN 'BH'
            ELSE [Event Location] END 
            END AS EventGroup
        ,CASE WHEN [Event Location] = 'HLMED' THEN 'MED'
            WHEN [Event Location] = 'HLRAD' THEN 'Imaging'
            WHEN [Event Location] IN ('HLOR','HLPACU') THEN 'OR/RR'
            WHEN [Event Location] IN ('HLNR','HLOB','HLLD') THEN 'OB/LD/NR'
            WHEN [Event Location] = 'HLCV' THEN 'PCU'
            WHEN [Event Location] IN ('HLICU','HLPACUOV') THEN 'ICU'
            WHEN [Event Location] = 'HLLAB' THEN 'LAB'
            WHEN [Event Location] = 'HLSUR' THEN 'Surg-Ped'
            WHEN [Event Location] = 'HLRT' THEN 'RT'
            WHEN [Event Location] = 'HLFANS' THEN 'FANS'
            WHEN [Event Location] = 'HLBUSOFF' THEN 'BIZ OFFICE'
            WHEN [Event Location] = 'HLPHA' THEN 'PHARM'
            WHEN [Event Location] = 'HLPSYCH' THEN 'BH'
            ELSE [Event Location] END AS EventLocation
FROM vw
WHERE Facility_MisFacID = 'HMC'
AND [Event Location] NOT IN ('HLECFE','HLECFN','HLECFS','HLED','HLSECURITY','HLEOC','HLIT','HLMSSNF','HLHPOC','HLED')
--AND EventDateTime >= '2017-01-01'
AND EventDateTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
AND [Order] = 1
AND IncidentType_RmIncidentTypeID = 'BEH'
GROUP BY [Event Location]
) t
GROUP BY t.Total, t.EventGroup, t.EventLocation
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
```

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE, not a language or tool for creating charts. What language do you use? Do you already have any code to share?

Comment: I'm using TSQL.

Comment: Here's my code: